# Is it possible to use Microsoft.Web.Administration to manipulate IIS 7 on cloud-based Appharbor or Azure?

Tags: iis, azure, appharbor

I've been hosting on [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) for some apps and it's been fantastic, but now I've run into the need to programmatically spin up virtual directories/applications and app pools in IIS. From my *thus far* limited understanding, this type of manipulation seems best fit for Microsoft.Web.Administration.

From my understanding of the AppHarbor architecture, that doesn't seem like a feasible expectation, is that correct?

And how about Azure? I've done some digging, and it seems to "fully support" IIS, but I'm not sure how/if the traditional concept of IIS applications even gels with these kinds of cloud based services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported on AppHarbor but note that you can [use our API to create new applications](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/api/applications-api).

It might be doable on Azure, especially if you opt for a vm role where you get to manage everything yourself. Configuring app pools is [apparently possible](http://things.smarx.com/#Configure IIS Application Pools).

Comment: Thanks....any plans on adding endpoints in the api to create "sub-applications" (roughly equivalent to applications in the iis realm -- not separate websites, but separate applications under one website)?

Comment: Not really, I think we're pretty happy with the current model. If you have a compelling use-case, we'd love to hear it though. Feel free to write support or add it to the feedback forum: https://appharbor.com/feedback